# Show a box with text when hovering an image

Tags: css, mousehover

I'm new to website building, so I'm really struggling!

I have an image of a PCB board / main board, that I want to display the text of the component when a user hovers this. I have got the image where I want it on my webpage (it will probably be a single page, as it is a subdomain of my Joomla site).

What is the easiest way of doing this?

I thought of creating different css styles, i.e. U5 for component U5 and U6 etc, and when the user hovers over U5 on the pic, it will display the text "U5 does this and that". Is that possible? If it is, how can I do it?

I have the pic up through the index.php on the webspace, and have text that points into the css, but now i'm getting stuck!

Any help would be appreciated.
Kind Regards,
Matt

Comment: Google a bit more... there's planty of pure CSS examples of doing what you need! *How to add span description to images*. To add more fancy effects I can suggest you to start learning [jQuery](http://jquery.com) too! (BTW... please paste here a specific issue you have with some `code`, so we can get this party started)

Comment: Hi, sorry, Ive been Googling all day, and didnt come up with what I needed, so I thought some gurus would be able to help me. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Also thanks to you, I'm using the jqueru, jtip for my tooltip titles... :-)

Comment: You're welcome! :) You can just love it! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you need exactly 
but one of the simplest solutions is to divide img as a map and add alt text to it so it's displayed when user hover over.
See this example:
http://www.noobcube.com/tutorials/html-css/css-image-maps-a-beginners-guide-/
here is w3schools tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

or more advanced way is to display `<DIV>` elements instead of alt text

Comment: "alt" is for text description of the image for search engines and people with impaired vision. "title" is for tooltip text displayed on mouse over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking into the image map from the link you gave me there. It looks like it might be the way to go for me. Many thanks.

Comment: @ Nickolay - yes sorry you are right. i've mixed them up. Matt, it is Title tag that you are looking for then

Answer (score 0):

Just enter your text as title:

```
<a href="yadiyadiya.com" title="Text that you want to be appear when hover"><img name="logo" src="link to picture" width="40" height="40"></a>
```